# How to create a regular expression for these sentences?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning regular expressions and want to help me to create a regular expression in JavaScript for the following situation:

1- I want detect when the user puts this in a textbox: "Please **read out the results**" or "can you please **list the results**?"

The regular expressions must detect [read out|list] (any word) results

How can create this regular expression in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: You can play around with regular expressions [at regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/).

Comment: @Pointy I learned a lot in this site and always use it.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'm watching the site right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

`((read out)|(list))([a-zA-Z ])*(results)`

Comment: FYI, you don't need to put "read out" and "list" in parens there - and this would match jsut "read out" or "list" on its own - so you don't need the ([a-zA-Z ])* at the end unless you wanted to capture it.

Answer (score 3):

This regex should work:

```
/(read out|list) \w+ results/
```

Comment: (?:read out|list) for a non-capturing regex that's slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one?

(read out|list)(.*?)(results)

Answer (score 0):

This might work with your problem:

```
(?:^|\b)(read out|list)\s(\w+)\s(results?)(?:\b|$)
```

I added \b at the begining to make sure it doesn't match with "playlist with result" for example

You can test it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

Comment: Thanks SeRPRo! I'm testing the expression in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and works perfect.